# Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Screenshot of the requirements file]

> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.

> 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart'
> ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String toString() =>
> fromUtf8(addressOf);
> ^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59:
> Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
> context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
> ^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17:
> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.   static
> Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
> ^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

> 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
> ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
> knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
> ^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.

> 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
> ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
> addressOf.cast().elementAt(28).cast();
> ^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
> 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.

> 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   LOGFONT get elfLogFont =>
> addressOf.cast().ref;
> ^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
> 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.

> 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String get elfFullName =>
> addressOf
> ^^^^^^^^^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line:
>   1035
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>   Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

Comment: You probably have the `ffi` package constrained to < 1 in your pubspec.yaml. Check in your pubspec.lock what versions are resolved for win32 and ffi.

Comment: For the future try making you question description shorter, people are more likely to answer a short yet clear question. Good lock coding :)

Answer (score 97):

I got this error today.
Here is what I did,

1. Deleted `.idea` folder and `build` folder as well as `pubspec-lock`
   file.
2. run `flutter pub get`

After these 2 simple steps, Project compiled without any errors.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed an issue for me with a project that I hadn't ran in months.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, but I'm really worried about other projects, why is this happening? its because of flutter/dart upgrades? or Android studio upgrades? why a dependency broke?

Comment: i didn't found .idea folder but deleted build folder and pubspec-lock file solving my issue

Comment: Those plethora of errors surely sounded much more alarming than I would expect to solve with a simple solution like this. But it does work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you

Comment: Not solved the issue. I have tried 2 times

Answer (score 24):

I find solution. Delete those file from folder

".idea" file

"build" file

"pubspec-lock" file.

After delete "flutter clean" form terminal. Then "pub get".

Comment: Thanks after receiving a project from a collegue developing on windows, I couldn't get the project to run on linux with a supposedly newer flutter toolchain. After setting dependency overrides for flutter_svg, intl, image and xml packages, your solution was the last stepstone to an apk.

Answer (score 16):

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter pub upgrade

Comment: This fix my problem btw

Comment: this fix my issue good answer man

Answer (score 14):

You should search which dependency broke your build :

```
flutter pub deps
```

Find globally `win32` in the result, and take the faulty dependency.

For me, it was `path_provider`:

```
|-- path_provider 1.6.18 <- Latest version 2.0.1
|   |-- flutter...
|   |-- path_provider_linux 0.0.1+2
|   |   |-- flutter...
|   |   |-- path...
|   |   |-- path_provider_platform_interface...
|   |   '-- xdg_directories 0.1.2
|   |       |-- meta...
|   |       |-- path...
|   |       '-- process 4.1.0
|   |           |-- file...
|   |           |-- path...
|   |           '-- platform...
|   |-- path_provider_macos 0.0.4+4
|   |   '-- flutter...
|   |-- path_provider_platform_interface 1.0.3
|   |   |-- flutter...
|   |   |-- meta...
|   |   |-- platform 3.0.0
|   |   '-- plugin_platform_interface...
|   '-- path_provider_windows 0.0.4+1
|       |-- ffi 0.1.3
|       |-- flutter...
|       |-- meta...
|       |-- path...
|       |-- path_provider_platform_interface...
|       '-- win32 1.7.3 <--- Here
|           '-- ffi...
```

Go to https://pub.dev/ and take the latest version. Then, make `futter clean && flutter pub get` and try to rebuild your app.

Comment: How did you know it was 'path_provider'

Answer (score 8):

Delete:

```
-> .idea folder
->  build folder 
->  pubspec-lock file.
```

Then:

```
run flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading all the packages to the latest version fixed my issue. since it's been quite a while since I last opened this project.

Answer (score 1):

first clean your Flutter Project and then run flutter pub get. hope it will work you
else Follow these procedures

**1. Delete .idea folder
2. Delete  build folder
3. Delete  pubspec-lock file.**

after That again run this command
**flutter pub get**

DONE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should search which dependency broke your build:

1. first there is an android studio plugin "Flutter Enhancement suite" install it
   it will show you which dependency need to be update to newer version.
2. Dependencies that are conflicting change them to any like
   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
   path_provider: any
3. run pub get.
4. go to pub pubspec.lock file
5. search for dependencies version that you changed to any in step 2.
6. replace versions in pubspec.yaml .
   and its done[enter image Flutter Enhancement suite[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieDCM.png)

[how to upgrade dependencies within android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weCJd.png)

[How to find perfect version for conflicting versions that we change with any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDw2J.png)

Answer (score 0):

first of all delete these file one by one

```
.idea folder
build folder 
pubspec-lock file.
```

and then run the following commands:

```
flutter clean;flutter pub get;
```