# Flutter - Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I'm building object-detecting object with flutter and yolov4. As I just copy [Texmexmax](https://github.com/TexMexMax/object_detection_flutter)'s code to execute, it shows wrong message.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in object_detection_flutter-master...
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/delegates/gpu_delegate.dart:58:10: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2'.
 - 'TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2' is from 'package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/types.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        .addressOf);
         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/delegates/metal_delegate.dart:42:70: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'TFLGpuDelegateOptions'.
 - 'TFLGpuDelegateOptions' is from 'package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/types.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        TFLGpuDelegateOptions.allocate(allowPrecisionLoss, waitType).addressOf);
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
 - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
                        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
 - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,

                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:6:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteInterpreter' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteInterpreter extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:9:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteInterpreterOptions' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteInterpreterOptions extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:12:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteModel' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteModel extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:15:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteTensor' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteTensor extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:18:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteDelegate' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteDelegate extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\winnie\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\winnie\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I had try all the ways in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug) and [anothers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67651806/error-the-getter-addressof-isnt-defined-for-the-class-utf8). Also I had upgrade pub, win32 ,and ffi, all of them didn't work for me. I guess the reason may cause the problem because it direct to the wrong file or others? I have no idea what can I do to fix the problem. Is there any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing same problem, Actually the problem is because of older dependencies, to check which dependencies are creating problems run following command

```
flutter pub deps
```

in my case it gives following output

```
|-- image 2.1.19
|   |-- archive 2.0.13
|   |   |-- args 1.6.0
|   |   |-- crypto 2.1.5
|   |   |   |-- collection...
|   |   |   |-- convert...
|   |   |   '-- typed_data...
|   |   '-- path...
|   |-- meta...
|   '-- xml 4.5.1
|       |-- collection...
|       |-- convert 2.1.1
|       |   |-- charcode...
|       |   '-- typed_data...
|       |-- meta...
|       '-- petitparser 3.1.0
|           '-- meta...
|-- path_provider 1.6.28
|   |-- flutter...
|   |-- path_provider_linux 0.0.1+2
|   |   |-- flutter...
|   |   |-- path...
|   |   |-- path_provider_platform_interface...
|   |   '-- xdg_directories 0.1.2
|   |       |-- meta...
|   |       |-- path...
|   |       '-- process 4.2.3
|   |           |-- file 6.1.2
|   |           |   |-- meta...
|   |           |   '-- path...
|   |           |-- path...
|   |           '-- platform...
|   |-- path_provider_macos 0.0.4+8
|   |   '-- flutter...
|   |-- path_provider_platform_interface 1.0.4
|   |   |-- flutter...
|   |   |-- meta...
|   |   |-- platform 3.0.0
|   |   '-- plugin_platform_interface 1.0.3
|   |       '-- meta...
|   '-- path_provider_windows 0.0.4+3
|       |-- ffi...
|       |-- flutter...
|       |-- meta...
|       |-- path...
|       |-- path_provider_platform_interface...
|       '-- win32 1.7.4+1
|           '-- ffi...
```

So, image and path_provider are creating problems. To upgrade dependencies edit pubspec.yaml manually and then pub get or run following commands

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
flutter pub get
```

And then

```
flutter run
```